# g++ compile error (Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64)

Tags: c++

When I compile code by g++-4.9

```
g++ main.cpp base_server.cpp base_server.hpp threaded_server.cpp threaded_server.hpp
```

I'm getting error:

```
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "BaseServer::~BaseServer()", referenced from:
      ThreadedServer::~ThreadedServer() in ccQVIp8S.o
      ThreadedServer::~ThreadedServer() in ccQVIp8S.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
make: *** [all] Error 1
```

When I compile by clang++ there are no any errors and warning. How to compile it by g++ ?

base_server.hpp: https://gist.github.com/yutkin/ccecf7d6132ab63db3bd

base_server.cpp: https://gist.github.com/yutkin/833bf593cf1775b3cb21

threaded_server.hpp:  https://gist.github.com/yutkin/61ef0a91f1e1c811334b

threaded_server.cpp: https://gist.github.com/yutkin/62821e6791565a54edac

OS X 10.11.1

Comment: probably not related to your problem, but you mustn't directly compile header files. Remove `*.hpp` from args to `g++`

Answer (score 0):

`BaseServer::~BaseServer()` was `inline`. Without `inline` all works properly.